# React Child Component In Different Part of DOM

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to reference / include a child react component that is **NOT** a DOM tree descendent?

The use case is a react component comprised of a button and modal (the button shows / hides the modal). The modal is a bootstrap modal and it renders incorrectly unless placed as a direct child of `<body></body>` (due to some position: fixed css in the content). I want to insert the button in one place and the modal in a different place but am trying to structure as a single react component.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to structure it as a one component. Those are two separate components. You have teo options: Include modal in html and call it using jQuery inside the button component. Use a global event system e.g. Flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference non-react DOM from a react component,

TEMPLATE:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

JSX:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    showModal:function(){
        // inject modal
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'modal';
        iDiv.className = 'block';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = 'DONE!';
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div onClick={this.showModal}>CLICK ME (R. component)</div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

The problem is worst in the other way (non-react --> react)

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dnty58y/1/